# Is the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \int_{-\infty}^\infty dy \frac{e^{i a x}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ convergent?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, fourier-transform, convolution, multiple-integral

Is the integral
$$I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \int_{-\infty}^\infty dy \frac{e^{i a x}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$
convergent for real $a$?

I have an idea to calculate it but I am not sure if it is correct:

First I consider

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \int_{-\infty}^\infty dy \frac{e^{i a x}}{\sqrt{(c_1-x)^2+(c_2-y)^2}}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \int_{-\infty}^\infty dy \ f_1(c_1-x,c_2-y)f_2(x,y)$$
with $f_1(x,y)=1/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $f_2(x,y)=e^{i a x}$.
Their Fourier transforms are $\mathcal F(f_1)=F_1(k_1,k_2)=1/\sqrt{k_1^2+k_2^2}$ and $\mathcal F(f_2)=F_2(k_1,k_2)=2\pi\delta(a+k_1)\delta(k_2)$.

From the convolution theorem, I think I can conclude that
$$(2\pi)\mathcal F(I)=F_1(k_1,k_2)F_2(k_1,k_2)=\frac{2\pi\delta(a+k_1)\delta(k_2)}{\sqrt{k_1^2+k_2^2}}$$
and therefore after taking the inverse Fourier transform
$$I=2\pi\frac{e^{i a c_1}}{|a|}.$$
Setting $c_1\rightarrow0$ would lead me to
$$I=\frac{2\pi}{|a|}.$$
Is this reasoning correct? Is there a way to figure out if the integral is convergent from some other argument?

Comment: Notice that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\sim\frac{1}{|y|}$ as $y\to\infty$, therefore the integral over $y$ diverges.

Comment: Thanks... Can you point me to why the convolution argument fails?

Comment: The convolution argument is valid if the convolution integral exists (i.e., is finite), but that is precisely what you are trying to prove. (Notice that the double integral converges if the integration over $x$ is performed first:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty dy \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \frac{e^{i a x}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
=2\int_{-\infty}^\infty dy\,K_0(|ay|)=\frac{2\pi}{|a|},
$$
which coincides with the result you obtained. However, the double integral diverges if the integration over $y$ is performed first.)